# Backbone. Fetch Model (JSON issue)

Tags: backbone.js

Im trying to fetch this Model in a nice way but dont really get it to work as i want.
The model gets fetched every second by a `setInterval();`. I do that because there is this backend system that are able to change the json that the model holds. The problem is that i dont know how to get a hold of ALL the json.

Right now i can only access "0"(question and id) and set that on the Model. I want to be able to access all the JSON and set on the Model. How would i parse that?

My json looks like this:

```
{
"0": [
    {
        "question": "lorem ispum",
        "id": "1"
    }
],
"1": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "alternative": "lorem ispum",
        "percent": "14.0000",
        "total": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "alternative": "lorem ispum",
        "percent": "14.0000",
        "total": "7"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "alternative": "lorem ispum",
        "percent": "60.0000",
        "total": "30"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "alternative": "lorem ispum",
        "percent": "12.0000",
        "total": "6"
    }
]
```

}

And this is my Model

```
QuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
id: "",
url: function() {
    return "api/?action=getQuestionData&question_id="+this.id;  
},

parse: function (response) {
    return response[0][0];
}
```

});

Comment: is it possible for example to return both [0][0] and [0][1] in the Model?

Comment: Thank you, works just like i wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone does not support nested data out of the box. I would do the following:

```
QuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
    id: "",
    url: function() {
        return "api/?action=getQuestionData&question_id="+this.id;  
    },

    parse: function (response) {
        return { question: response["0"][0], answers:  response["1"] };
    }
});
```

Then you can access your properties like `questionModel.get('question').id` and your answers like `questionModel.get('answers')[0].percent`